# Data validation with macro

Tags: excel

I have one Column with notes in it and other columns have some data from it and want check the data is correct or not by selecting columns and if it not correct it should highlight the cell

Comment: In order to receive better help, please provide more information regarding your problem. Example data, and expected result etc etc...

Comment: Column 1 - Rate - 4453.00 Column 2 - Codes/CodeRanges1 - 154, 156, 160 Column 3 - Notes - If you are selecting codes 154, 156, 160 then you need to pay 4453.00 I have such kind of data in my excel and now I want check is the data mentioned in column 1 is correct with respect to data I have in column 3 note by giving the condition of selecting column 1 and column 3, as well as column 2 and column 3

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a stab in the dark. 
I have no Idea how the check is supposed to work. The following macro just checks if the currently selected cell is equal to "s". If so the cell's background color is set to red.

```
   If ActiveCell.Value = "s" Then
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    End If
```

Comment: Column 1 - Rate  - 4453.00

Column 2 - Codes/CodeRanges1 - 154, 156, 160

Column 3 - Notes - If you are selecting codes 154, 156, 160 then you need to pay 4453.00

I have such kind of data in my excel and now I want check is the data mentioned in column 1 is correct with respect to data I have in column 3 note by giving the condition of selecting column 1 and column 3, as well as column 2 and column 3.

Comment: try attaching a screen dump in your original post.